# OS X not allowing me to rename a folder

Tags: macos, permissions

Can anyone thing of a reason why OS X would not allow me to do this?  I seem to have total permissions...

```
new-host-4:Desktop michael$ whoami
michael
new-host-4:Desktop michael$ ls -ltdr 2008_12_12/
drwxrwxrwx+ 5 michael  wheel  170 Mar 28 18:23 2008_12_12/
new-host-4:Desktop michael$ mv 2008_12_12/ foo
mv: rename 2008_12_12/ to foo: Permission denied
new-host-4:Desktop michael$
```

Thanks!
/YGA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Renaming a file is considered a modification of the directory it is in. What does...

```
ls -lde .
```

...tell you about your ability to modify the directory you're in (apparently "Destkop")?

2) There could already be a "foo" in the directory you're in, and you might not have privileges to replace it. What does...

```
ls -lde foo
```

...tell you?

3) The "`+`" at the end of the permissions for "`2008_12_12/`" means it has an ACL (Access Control List == additional permissions/restrictions) attached. What does...

```
ls -lde 2008_12_12
```

...tell you?

Comment: Very nice... the answer was #3!

Answer (score -1):

In OSX depending on where the directory is located you need to sudo the operation. I think if it's outside your home directory (/Users/[user] or ~), it requires sudo.

Comment: It seems to be on his desktop: `new-host-4:Desktop michael$`